# Is Autocommit mode efficient?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am using python3.7 and sqlite3 module, with "auto commit" mode (i.e. creating the connection object by setting the isolation_level to None). I want to check if this is as efficient as possible? This is how I created by connection object.

`conn = sqlite3.connect(DATABASE_NAME, check_same_thread=False, isolation_level=None)`

Comment: What I mean is, what effects does "autocommit" mode have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python `sqlite3` module has some odd behaviour with respect to transactions, and the documentation on the subject is rather confusing. Its reference to "autocommit mode" is especially confusing - I think there is a meaning for this term in Python which is different to the term used in the underlying SQLite library. I'll just avoid that term altogether in this answer.

If `isolation_level` is NOT `None` (indeed the default is `""` which is not `None`) then transactions will sometimes be started automatically. It's up to you to commit them or roll them back, either by calling `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK` explicitly or by using the connection as a context manager:

```py
# Approach 1: transactions start automatically
conn = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db)
with conn:
    values = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in conn.execute("SELECT a, b FROM Foo")]
    # transaction starts here - in between the two statements!
    conn.execute("UPDATE Foo SET a=? WHERE b=?", (values[0][0] + 1, values[0][1]))
    # At this point, with conn: will automatically commit/rollback the transaction
```

(By the way this is a very poor way to increment a value. You don't need to read all rows, and you don't even need separate `SELECT` and `UPDATE` statements! But this is meant to illustrate how the transactions work, not how to write good SQL.)

In the above example, Python will *NOT* start a transaction when it gets to the `SELECT` statement, but *WILL* start a transaction when it gets to the `INSERT` statement. The `with conn:` context manager will ensure the transaction is either committed (if there's no exception) or rolled back (if there is an exception) at the end of the block.

I could say more about when and why transactions are started automatically, but my advice is to set `isolation_level` to `None`, which stops Python from ever starting transactions automatically. You can then begin them manually for yourself, as progmatico's answer said:

```py
# Approach 2: you manually start transactions in your code
conn = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db, isolation_level=None)
with conn:
    conn.execute("BEGIN")  # Starts the transaction
    values = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in conn.execute("SELECT a, b FROM Foo")]
    conn.execute("UPDATE Foo SET a=? WHERE b=?", (values[0][0] + 1, values[0][1]))
    # At this point, with conn: will automatically commit/rollback the transaction
```

Or don't use them at all:

```py
# Approach 3: no explicit transactions at all
conn = sqlite3.connect(path_to_db, isolation_level=None)
values = [(row[0], row[1]) for row in conn.execute("SELECT a, b FROM Foo")]
conn.execute("UPDATE Foo SET a=? WHERE b=?", (values[0][0] + 1, values[0][1]))
```

In the last code snippet, we never started a transaction (and neither did Python!), so the underlying SQLite library automatically put each of the two statements in their own implicit transactions. (This is what the underlying SQLite library documentation calls "autocommit mode". Oops, I did mention that term again!)

So, hopefully you can see that it doesn't make sense to ask whether `isolation_level=None` makes your code more efficient. It lets you choose when to start and finish transactions, if at all, as in approach 2 vs approach 3. But it's still up to you when you do that, and that's what affects the efficiency of your program. If you're inserting a lot of records, it's more efficient to do them in one transaction, like approach 2. But you don't want to keep transactions open for too long because that could block other threads/processes trying to use that database. And there's typically not much speed benefit to executing `SELECT` statements in a transaction, so approach 3 might be the way to go (but a transaction might be necessary for correctness anyway, depending on the application).

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is literally written [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#controlling-transactions).

It basically says that you can stop the `sqlite3` Python module from starting transactions implicitly on any data modification statement you send, allowing you the user, to assume the control of transactions ocurring in the underlying sqlite library with `BEGIN`, `ROLLBACK`, `SAVEPOINT`, and `RELEASE` statements in your code.

This is useful to group several statements that should be executed as part of a single transaction, instead of having every single modification statement executing in its own implicit transaction.